# Redirect user to a custom url after submitting the comment

Tags: comments

After someone submits a comment this line of codes redirects him to the post (i believe).
Can I modify the code in order to redirect him to a custom URL?

do_action('comment_form', $post->ID)

Ty for the answer,

UPDATE:

my comments.php

```
<form> 
  .......
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit" />
  <input type="hidden" name="my_redirect_to" value="http://www.google.com"; />
  <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
  <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
  </form>
```

my functions.php

```
add_action('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_to_thank_page'); // Redirect to thank you post after comment
   function redirect_to_thank_page() {
       if ( isset( $_POST['my_redirect_to'] ) ) 
       return $_POST['my_redirect_to']; 
   }
```

The code does not work, it's not redirecting to google.com for example.

Any ideas why?
Ty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite; the redirect occurs inline inside `wp-comments-post.php`

Use the filter `comment_post_redirect` to pass back any URL of your choice. Arguments passed are the default redirect & comment object, respectively.

Based on your comments, here's a suggestion:

```
function wpse_58613_comment_redirect( $location ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['my_redirect_to'] ) ) // Don't use "redirect_to", internal WP var
        $location = $_POST['my_redirect_to'];

    return $location;
}

add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'wpse_58613_comment_redirect' );
```

Comment: Ty very much, I can't use a filter though.... is there a method to modify the form directly inside comments.php?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change where the form is *submitted* to? Or what happens once a comment is posted?

Comment: i cannot use filters because I am using a custom code which passes a variable http://www.mysitec.om/post/customvar/ - and maybe I can use something like <input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="http://domain.com/post/customvar" /> in comments.php

Comment: Sorry, but you're not making an awful lot of sense - I've taken a guess at what you're after (see the revision).

Comment: I think it work, ty very much:) Had to replace google.com with my actual url

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I dont think you necessarily have to sanitize the $_POST['my_redirect_to'] variable, because WordPress does it for you in wp_safe_redirect(). If you replace it with something that won't pass wp_safe_redirect()'s criteria then you'll be redirected to wp-admin. But I could be wrong on this so use at your own discretion.

Comment: @NickBudden Fair point (removed comment), though it's worth noting `wp_safe_redirect()` only checks if the hostname is valid - everything else is fair game.

Comment: You can redirect to the initial url through `$location = wp_get_referer();`.